# remove empty line printed from hive query output using python

Tags: python, mysql, hadoop, hive

i am performing a hive query and storing the output in a tsv file in the local FS. I am running a for loop for the hive query and passing different parameters. If the hive query returns no output once in the for loop it prints an empty line in the tsv file. This causes NULL values to be pushed to my DB in the backend. Hence, after the for loop runs and the file is created - i have the below code to remove all the empty lines printed, but it doesn't work.

How do i remove the empty line from this file?

```
` 395.9   429.61  PT  
                       `
```

code:

```
with open('file.tsv','r+w') as file:
        for line in file:
          if line.strip():
            file.write(line)
```

thanks

Comment: Why do i get a downvote - @To Click or Not to Click

Comment: that actually wasn't me

Comment: I just came to edit your formatting... I can cancel out the down vote with an up vote, or I can down vote to prove that I didn't down vote earlier?

Comment: cool @ToClickorNottoClick For some reason i cant put in that empty line in the output i get. formatting issues

Comment: Where is the empty line in that file?

Comment: The empty line is after the first line. I can't format it here in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would open the input file and write the non-empty lines to a second file:

```
with open('file.tsv') as infile, open('filtered_file.tsv', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip():
            outfile.write(line)
```

If you want to filter the file inplace you can use `FileInput` with the `inplace` option:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("infile", inplace=1):
    if line.strip():
        print line
```

however, this uses an intermediate file and may not work in low disk space situations.

To filter the file inplace without allocating any additional disk space you could try something like this:

```
with open('file.tsv', 'r+') as infile:
    read_pos = write_pos = 0
    line = infile.readline()
    while line:
        read_pos += len(line)
        if line.strip():
            infile.seek(write_pos)
            infile.write(line)
            write_pos += len(line)
        infile.seek(read_pos)
        line = infile.readline()
    # update file size to the new, possibly reduced, size
    infile.truncate(write_pos)
```