# Check for an empty line in a tsv file and not do a mysql insert for that empty line

Tags: python, mysql

I am currently doing a mysql insert by reading a tsv file directly. The issue i am experiencing right now is that NULL values are being inserted in the DB when there is an empty line in the tsv file.

I wrote the following code snippet to read the entire TSV file line by line and only do an insert if the line is not empty.

```
with open('file.tsv','r+w') as file:
    for line in file:
      if len(line)>0:
        #upload to DB
        conn = connect_db()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        try:
          cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "file.tsv" INTO TABLE abcd FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@col1,@col2,@col3) set a=@col1,b=@col2,grid=@col3,date='"+date+"', pipeline='"+pipeline_name+"'")

          conn.close()
        except:
          print (cursor._last_executed)
          raise
```

Sample wrong Mysql output after reading from a TSV file -

```
13 | 2014-06-16 | apollo   | PT   |           380 |              316 |
| 14 | 2014-06-16 | apollo   |      |             0 |             NULL |
```

Desired Mysql output-

```
13 | 2014-06-16 | apollo   | PT   |           380 |              316 |
13 | 2014-06-17 | apollo   | PT   |           350 |              312 |
```

Can someone please let me know how can I achieve the above.

Comment: There are too many ways to do this for this to be a good question. Of the top of my head, you could pre-process the file are remove empty lines without changing your query or do a line by line insert, skipping empty lines.

Comment: As you can see above...i am trying to do a line by line insert...but it doesn't work..so can you please suggest a working method? @LegoStormtroopr

Comment: Its not line by line, you are throwing the whole file at the database - also, your code has many syntax errors.

Comment: A method for pre-processing the _tsv_ file to remove empty lines was suggested in your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196181/remove-empty-line-printed-from-hive-query-output-using-python. Why don't you do that, and then execute the db load with the filtered file?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - I am throwing the whole file at the database..because I did not have the code before to eliminate empty lines. The code I have mentioned above was just written after I came across this issue. I have edited the question to be more specific - Can the hold be removed now?

Comment: @mhawke - Thanks for replying back to that question - but I found this method more easy to do. That step involves one more step of processing the entire file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two problems with your code:

1. Iterating through a text file line-by-line will never return an empty string (`len(line)==0`) <strike>except at the end of the file</strike> **EDIT: not even at end-of-file with Python's standard file iterator**. That's because the returned line will always include the end-of-line character(s) even for a blank line. Try `if len(line.strip())>0` to check for lines which contain something other than whitespace and EOL character(s).
2. After you've got that fixed, you have a bigger problem: your code tries to load the whole file in at once, rather than loading individual lines. You'll likely need to restructure it to use the standard SQL `INSERT` statement rather than the MySQL's `LOAD DATA` extension.

   The end result should look something like this:

   ```
   db = ...
   cur = db.cursor()

   for line in f:
     if len(line.strip()) > 0:
       # tab-separated, right?
       fields = line.strip().split('\t')
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_foo (a,b,c) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", fields)
   ```

Comment: Awesome...trying this out right now. I was actually not processing the file in my code before and just doing a direct insert into MYSQL after loading the data from the TSV file, but thanks for bringing it to my notice. After implementing the code above, it makes sense to a line by line insert - @Dan

Answer (score 0):

The way you are opening the file, you will have length of empty line equal to 1 due to EOL character. A better approach is to use Python's [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html) with `delimiter = '\t'`

And secondly as @dan said, why are you trying to insert the whole file rather than doing it line by line?